# TortoiseSVN uses DirectUIHWND?

Tags: tortoisesvn

You'll notice TortoiseSVN 1.7.0 (on Windows 7) shows such a window:

```
TortoiseSVN

(!) Upgrade working copy

    This will upgrade your working copy to the new 1.7 format and make it unusable for older clients.

  -> Upgrade the working copy
     to the new 1.7 format.

  -> Cancel
     keep the current format.
```

or, reverting the deleted file:

```
TortoiseSVN

(!) Confirm revert 

    Do you want to revert 'AboutDlg.cpp'?

    All changes since the last update will be lost!

    -> Revert
       All changes will be lost.

    -> Cancel
       Leave all changes.
```

Microsoft Spy++ says it's child window class is **DirectUIHWND**! Isn't it an undocumented secret technology?

Where can I find the code/usage of DirectUIHWND in TortoiseSVN source code set?

*note:*

I found a text in .pot file.

C:\A\tortoisesvn\Languages\TortoiseUI.pot(1818):msgid "All changes since the last update will be lost!"

http://tortoisesvn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Languages/TortoiseUI.pot

How are they used??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CTaskDialog** may do it, so check the msdn reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293651.aspx

CTaskDialog seems to be part of *Microsoft Foundation Class* shipped with *Visual Studio 2010*.

*note*:

CTaskDialog usage is found around WcUpgradeCommand.h.

http://tortoisesvn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/TortoiseProc/Commands/WcUpgradeCommand.h

EDITED: wrong link

Comment: [TaskDialog function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760540(v=VS.85).aspx) will be implementation of CTaskDialog.
So, DirectUIHWND is still secret tech!